# Problemas pegar XML en Stack Overflow en español

Tags: xml

estoy intentando subir un pequeño XML para una cuestión, pero el editor de stackoverflow parece interpretarlo y no muestra nada. 
¿Debo encerrar el XML entre algún tipo de carácter especial?
Gracias.

Comment: Debes seleccionar el código que quieras que no se interprete y pulsar al icono que tiene las llaves "{ }" dentro de la barra de herramientas del propio editor.

Comment: Muchas gracias @phpMyGuel. También he comprobado que añadiendo 3 comillas simples invertidas, antes y después del XML, también lo muestra.